# The term 'else' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program In VScode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

[Here is the screenshot that I took](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKIO3.png)

Please help me to solve it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int speed;
    printf("Enter your speed as an integer:");
    scanf("%d",&speed);
    if (speed<65)
     printf("NO speeding ticket");
    else
     printf("Speeding Ticket");
    return 0;
}
```

At the terminal it says The term "else" is not recognized.

Comment: You have an `&` in your file name. The shell recognizes that as an operator and splits the command in `if` and `else` where the latter is no valid command

Comment: You should check what characters are allowed in filenames for your operating system. That's not related to C or VS Code at all.

Comment: @Gerhardh it works Sir. Thank You. I am just a beginner to programming.

Comment: That is not really a programming issue. You will very likely run into the same problem at other places if you provide such a filename to any program on command line.